# How can I extract the computational graph of PyTorch model?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm trying to extract the computational graph of PyTorch model like 'onnx.model.graph' API which can generate the computational graph of ONNX model.

I found two or three ways to make the computational graph in pytorch. But, I'm not sure which one is correct one.

1. **'torch.nn.Module'** API of PyTorch itself.
2. **'torch.jit'** supports to make the pytorch script which has the model's information.
3. **'onnx.export'**. I think this is the common way to be used.

Please let me know which one is correct one or tell me the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what you are trying to achieve. By default, PyTorch constructs a computational graph dynamically on each forward pass and may be different based on the input data (e.g., if you have an underlying if condition, only the graph of a single branch will be constructed).

As far as I know, when you use TorchScript, all conditional logic will be preserved in the graph. However, exporting to ONNX is done via tracing (unless something has changed in recent versions), and some of the complex Torch operators will be replaced by the combination of simpler ONNX operators.

Therefore, each approach can be correct, but at the same time, the produced results may be different.

Comment: Yes, ONNX export requires that you specify an input shape to trace the computational graph.